# Redirect only error of git command to a log file

Tags: git, logging, error-handling, git-fetch

I am writing a script that uses `git fetch --all && git fetch --all --tags` to fetch all the branches and tags of all the remotes.

What I want to do is, ignore/don't display fetching output, but if the fetch fails, then do something (like writing error message to a log file and mail it). How can i ignore normal output but write only error to log file if the command fails?

OS: CentOS 6.5

git: 2.1.0-rc1

Thank You!

> Update-1

`git-fetch` writes to stderr even on successful fetching. So if I do

`git fetch a.j 1>success 2>errlog`, then even on successful fetching I get this in error file:

From xx.xx.xx.xx:user.name/repo

- [new branch]      for/lib.base/core -> a.j/for/lib.base/core
- [new branch]      for/master/lib.base_core -> a.j/for/master/lib.base_core
- [new branch]      for/master/memmgr -> a.j/for/master/memmgr

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Unix `stderr` descriptor `2` to capture the error to a file :

```
git fetch --all && git fetch --all --tags 1>/dev/null 2>error.log
```

`1>/dev/null` is the normal stdout outputs, whereas
`2>error.log` logs the errors to the `error.log` file.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly well in normal usecase. but `git-fetch` sends the list of new branches created also on stderr. So the above command writes to error.log even on successful fetching.